# Connecting Erlang nodes when an internal and external IP address are at play

Tags: erlang

I have two virtual machines that use internal IP addresses to speak to one another while the outside world knows about these VMs only via external IP addresses.

I have a distributed cache that makes use of the two VM's - each has an Erlang Node that must communicate with the other. I *also* have Erlang clients of the cache, on other machines, that need to communicate with one (or both) of the Erlang caching nodes on the VMs.

So, if I have the cache nodes named using the internal IP addresses then they can communicate with one another, but no other Erlang node can interact with them. But, if I name the cache nodes using the VM's external IP addresses, then the outside Erlang nodes can communicate with the cache nodes, but the cache nodes cannot communicate with one another.

Is there something I can do about this other than using an http or socket-based interface that does *not* rely on joining the nodes into a mesh?

Comment: I think your question winds up being more about virtual networking than erlang. Try editing your question with a more detail explanation of the topology involved, include what VM environment you're in, and add a tag like "virtualization" and "networking" or whatever as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is **definitely doable**.

#### Preliminaries

Erlang's distribution addresses are in two parts: the node name and the host name. They are separated by the `@` sign.

Host names can be numeric IPv4 addresses. They can also be domain names. There are two distinct modes, where host names are short (single word, e.g. `vm1`) and where they are long (several words, e.g. `vm1.domain.com`). IP addresses are long names. Nodes started in one mode (short or long) can only communicate with nodes started in the same mode. Nodes are also protected by a cookie: a node will only accept incoming connection with a matching cookie. The easiest is to start all nodes of a given cluster with the same cookie.

When an Erlang node tries to connect to another Erlang node, it needs to find the IP address of the distant node. If it is the same as itself, it will simply try to connect on the local host. If it is different, it will try to resolve this host name to an IP address.

Then it will connect to the `epmd` daemon on this host to be told which port Erlang is running. `epmd` as well as Erlang nodes listen on all interfaces (by default).

#### Solution and example

Based on this mechanism, you could use either short or long names, but exploit the resolution mechanism. The easiest on Unix would be to configure different IPs on each `/etc/hosts` of your machines (especially on the two virtual machines) so they will connect to each other through their private addresses, while being accessed through their public addresses.

Let's say that Virtual machine A (VM A) has private IP address 10.0.0.2 and public IP address 123.4.5.2 and VM B has private IP address 10.0.0.3 and public IP address 123.4.5.3. Let's also say that you decided to go for short names.

You could put on VM A this entry in `/etc/hosts`:

```
10.0.0.3 vmb
```

You could put the matching entry on VM B's `/etc/hosts`:

```
10.0.0.2 vma
```

And on all the external clients, you could put:

```
123.4.5.2 vma
123.4.5.3 vmb
```

You would start your nodes as follows:

```
# Node foo on VM A:
erl -sname foo@vma -cookie RANDOMCOOKIE
# Node foo on VM B:
erl -sname foo@vmb -cookie RANDOMCOOKIE
# Client nodes:
erl -sname client -cookie RANDOMCOOKIE
```

You can avoid the `/etc/hosts` edits on client nodes if you have a domain name (e.g. `yourdomain.com`) and you can get `vma.yourdomain.com` to resolve to 123.4.5.2. You can also use a specific [Erlang Inet configuration file](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/inet_cfg.html).

#### Security

Erlang distribution mechanism is not meant to be public facing. Besides, all communications will be unencrypted. I strongly suggest to **configure firewalls** on each host to only let connections from other cluster servers and **use SSL distribution**.

For the firewall: Erlang distribution uses port 4369 for `epmd` as well as random ports for each node. You can limit the range of these random ports by using Erlang kernel application environment settings `inet_dist_listen_min` and `inet_dist_listen_max`. You will need to allow incoming TCP connections on these ports, but only from other hosts of the cluster.

SSL distribution is quite complex to setup but [well documented](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/ssl/ssl_distribution.html). The main drawback in your case is that all connections should be over SSL, including those between the two virtual machines on their private network, and local connections to open remote shells.

Answer (score 4):

Before answering the question, I want to point out, that [Distributed Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html) is not secure and you should not use it outside of trusted local area network. (I had to leave that comment after I saw "external ip address", I assume it doesn't mean public). Below is a list of 4 important things, you should be aware of:

1. Ip address is part of the node name.

When you start a node, it is good to give it a name like this:

```
erl -name myname@192.168.0.1
```

When you try to connect to that node from other machine, you can use something like this in erlang shell:

```
net_kernel:connect('myname@192.168.0.1').
```

The important part is that node name: `'myname@192.168.0.1'` is an atom. It is not "name and ip" - it is one thing. Even, if your second node is on the same machine, you can't use:

```
net_kernel:connect('myname@127.0.0.1').
```

because it is different node name.

2. Connections are on top of TCP

This means, that to connect two nodes, only one has to see the other.

Example: you have:

- one node on a machine with external ip address (the client) and
- one node on a machine with internal ip address (the caching node)

than:

- you can't connect from client to caching node (because it can't see that ip address)
- you *can* connect from caching node to client (because caching node sees the external ip of client) and the connection is bidirectional!

In the second case, the connections is just as if they were on the same network. You only have to think about who should initialise the connection.

3. When you connect new node to existing cluster, it tries to connect to all other nodes.

If you don't want to that - use [hidden nodes](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html#id85406).

4. Make sure, that you use the same Erlang cookie everywhere.

But I think, you have that covered, if you were able connect other nodes.

The easiest solution is to use external ip addresses everywhere, because Erlang distribution was designed to run on local network. Harder solution involves making sure, that you connect from nodes in local network to nodes with external ip.