# In Elixir/Erlang, which port is used for `Node.connect`?

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp

One can init a Elixir node by iex using:

```
iex --sname node1@10.99.1.50 --cookie foo
```

And then another one can connect this node in REPL using:

```
Node.connect(:"node1@10.99.1.50")
```

It seems the connection is over TCP protocol. However, I didn't find a parameter in [document](http://erlang.org/doc/man/net_kernel.html#connect_node-1) to specify which port is used. Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Connecting nodes is handled by the [Erlang Port Mapping Daemon (epmd)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/epmd.html) which runs by default on port **4369**. From the documentation:

> A different port can be specified to allow several instances of epmd, representing independent clusters of nodes, to co-exist on the same host. All nodes in a cluster must use the same epmd port number.

The actual node opens a random(?) port and announces this along with its `sname` to the local `epmd`. When you now connect to `'node1@10.99.1.50'`, your Erlang VM will ask the remote `epmd` running on `10.99.1.50` on port 4369 for information on `'node1'`. It will answer with the actual port number to which your process then connects directly.

Answer (score 7):

As per this post [Erlang Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474591/connecting-erlang-nodes-when-an-internal-and-external-ip-address-are-at-play) Erlang uses port 4369 over TCP. The post has more information about this.

> For the firewall: Erlang distribution uses port **4369** for epmd as well as random ports for each node. You can limit the range of these random ports by using Erlang kernel application environment settings inet_dist_listen_min and inet_dist_listen_max. You will need to allow incoming **TCP connections** on these ports, but only from other hosts of the cluster.

You may also be interested in this: [Chris McCoord on the subject](https://dockyard.com/blog/2016/01/28/running-elixir-and-phoenix-projects-on-a-cluster-of-nodes?utm_campaign=elixir_radar_35&utm_medium=email&utm_source=RD%20Station)

Comment: Port 4369 is only used to communicate the actual ports.

Comment: @filmor seems to be correct. Thank you for the correction.